# Supertest is throwing 404 when url has a ? for optional parameter, any ideas?

Tags: javascript, node.js, supertest

I have a route like this:

```
router.delete("/:id?", controller);
```

and when i'm trying to test that route with supertest like this:

```
const res = await request(app)
    .delete(`${url}/credentials/123`)
    .send({
        payload
    });
```

the test fails because in the expect i'm waiting for a 500 in this case

```
expect(res.status).to.be.eql(500);
```

and it cames with a 404, like the route doesn't exists. But when i try my tests without the optional id, they pass the expect.

any ideas what could be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimal working example:

`app.js`:

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const { Router } = require("express");

app.use(express.json());
const router = new Router();

function controller(req, res) {
  res.sendStatus(500);
}
router.delete("/:id?", controller);

app.use("/api/credentials", router);

module.exports = app;
```

`app.test.js`:

```js
const app = require("./app");
const request = require("supertest");
const { expect } = require("chai");

describe("57872239", () => {
  it("should pass", async () => {
    const payload = {};
    const url = "/api";
    const res = await request(app)
      .delete(`${url}/credentials/123`)
      .send({ payload });
    expect(res.status).to.be.eql(500);
  });
});
```

Integration test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
  57872239
    ✓ should pass


  1 passing (42ms)

-------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File         |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
-------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files    |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 app.js      |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 app.test.js |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
-------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/mocha-chai-sinon-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/57872239

Answer (score 0):

This might happen when you forget to import the appropriate module containing your URL endpoint. E.g. you want to query against `InventoryModule`, you must include it in the `imports` section.

```
const moduleFixture: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
      expandVariables: true,
      load: config,
    }),
    DatabaseModule,
    AuthModule,
    InventoryModule,
    CompaniesModule,
    LoggerModule.forRoot(),
    EventEmitterModule.forRoot(),
  ],
  providers: [MailFacade],
})
  .overrideProvider(MailFacade)
  .useValue(mockMailFacade)
  .compile();
```